# Merging sublists in python

Tags: python

How do i merge `[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]` to `['a','b','c','d','e','f']`?

Comment: from functools import reduce
a = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, a)

Comment: import itertools
original_list = [[2,4,3],[1,5,6], [9], [7,9,0]]
new_merged_list = list(itertools.chain(*original_list))

Answer (score 21, accepted):

list concatenation is just done with the `+` operator.

so

```
total = []
for i in [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]:
    total += i

print total
```

Comment: This is the best solution, as it's the simplest. +1. However, you can simply do:
`new_list = old_list1 + old_list2`. Your's does the same thing, but you don't need to put them together in a list of lists first.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted it to work for an arbitrary list. I've since learnt you can do something like `sum([], [list1, list2, list3])`, and since sum calls the + operator, which for `[]` is the concatenation op, it will join them all for you.

Comment: @will Fully agree with you. ```total += i``` is a more generic solution.

Answer (score 40):

Using list comprehension:

```
ar = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
concat_list = [j for i in ar for j in i]
```

Comment: This is the fastest way, fwiw.  In terms of cpu cycles.

Comment: Totally the best way, as it's the most compact. But how does it work?

Comment: I love this! And I totally don't understand it! Please somebody explain. That is mindblowing.

Comment: This is double iteration in a list comprehension.  The first `for` picks out each list in `ar` as `j`, and the second `for` picks out each element in `j` as `i`.

Comment: Excellent! Can anyone tell me how can we do a type conversion for the items before adding to concat_list?

Comment: @Mainuddin One way is: `[int(j) for i in ar for j in i]`.  

For clarity, we could write OP's answer as `[element for sublist in data_in for element in sublist]`.  

You could also get unique elements of the list using `set()`: `[element for sublist in data_in for element in set(sublist)]` or `list.count()`: `[element for sublist in data_in for element in sublist if sublist.count(element) < 2]`.

Answer (score 8):

This would do:

```
a = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,a)
```

Comment: WHY?! this is completely over the top, why not just do `a = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]` `a[0]+a[1]`

Comment: Will that work if the list was `[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['d','e','f']] ?

Comment: obviously not, but that is not what the question was, and if you want it to work for arbitrarily long sets of flat lists, then [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14278710/432913) works and is much more readable

Comment: I agree your answer is much more readable :), I just gave an generic answer. :)

Comment: Apart from being slow(coz of `lambda`) this code will easily break if `a` is something like : `[('a','b','c'),['d','e','f']]`.

Comment: @Sibi - I normally dislike lambdas - i find they're a very easy way to make very unreadable code. This example i quite like for it's succinctness though

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Ofcourse, that code wasn't written to concatenate list and tuple ;)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - I don't see how this is relevant - if you pass the wrong arguments to a function, you're going to get a bad answer...

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary If you really want to make that code work, then you can do this for your case: `reduce(lambda x,y:list(x)+list(y),a)`

Comment: @Sibi Why not simply use `itertools.chain()`, which is built for such  for such purpose only and is very fast compared to your solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python#408281

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
sum([['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f']], [])
```

Or longer but faster:

```
[i for l in [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']] for i in l]
```

Or use `itertools.chain` as @AshwiniChaudhary suggested:

```
list(itertools.chain(*[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]))
```

Comment: `sum()` shouldn't be used for such things. As [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) say: **To concatenate a series of iterables, consider using itertools.chain().**

Answer (score 1):

Try the "extend" method of a list object:

```
 >>> res = []
 >>> for list_to_extend in range(0, 10), range(10, 20):
         res.extend(list_to_extend)
 >>> res
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Or shorter:

```
>>> res = []
>>> map(res.extend, ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]))
>>> res
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mergedlist = list_letters[0] + list_letters[1]
```

This assumes you have a list of a static length and you always want to merge the first two

```
>>> list_letters=[['a','b'],['c','d']]
>>> list_letters[0]+list_letters[1]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```