# Tokenize sentence function

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

I need to tokenize a sentence without using regex nor any imported module, but with the built-in split() function. The function should take a text as input and returns a list that contains the sentences in the text, delimited by '?', '!' and '.'
An example would be:

```
>>> t = "Are you out of your mind? I can't believe it! I'm so disappointed."
>>> get_sentences(t)
['Are you out of your mind', 'I can't believe it', 'I'm so disappointed']
```

Here is my work so far:

```
def get_sentences(text):
    l1 = text.split('.')
    for l2 in l1:
        l2 = l2.split('!')
        for l3 in l2:
            l3 = l3.split('?')
    return l1
```

Any help, please?

Comment: The posted code isn't valid (bad indentation).

Comment: In what way(s) does your code not answer the problem you are trying to solve?  And why do you think that it *should*?

Answer (score -1):

One way to solve the problem is to split the text progressively using one separator at a time and then combine the fragments with either `sum()` or `itertools.chain()`. The latter is much faster but requires an external module. The order of the separators does not matter. `strip`ping removes the unwanted whitespaces between the sentences.

```
sents = sum([sum([[z.strip() for z in y.split("?")] 
                             for y in x.split("!")], []) 
                             for x in t.split(".")], [])
```

There may be empty-string leftovers in the output. Get rid of them:

```
sents = [sent for sent in sents if sent]
#['Are you out of your mind', "I can't believe it", 
# "I'm so disappointed"]
```

Comment: You ended up with 4 items; solution should have 3.

Comment: thanks, do u know any other way to do that without sum() nor itertools.chain()? (I'm pretty limited in the use of modules and functions...) Is there a way to solve the problem by using loops and splits?

Comment: `sum()` is a built-in function. What's wrong with it?

Comment: If you cannot use the built-in function (you should have warned us), you can write your own based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14278710/4492932).